# Edit characater spacing (tracking) in TTF font

Tags: fonts, editing, truetype-fonts

I want to edit character spacing of a TTF font. I mean when you write "Hello", I need to change the font so that it was looking like "H e l l o". I have installed `TTFEdit` and in advanced I have found a bunch of parameters called `OS/2` but I don't understand how to change the spacing. Experimenting and manuals didn't help either. Please help. Maybe I need to use another tool?

Comment: This is usually called kerning, look for something like that...

Comment: There is nothing called kerning in parameters.

Comment: It's possible its an attribute to each character, not the font as a whole

Comment: Please tell me how? And also see the wiki where it is written:"Kerning adjusts the space between individual letter forms, while tracking (letter-spacing) adjusts spacing uniformly over a range of characters."  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) I need to change the **tracking**.

Comment: Someone also asked this, but I don't understand the solution: http://superuser.com/questions/61892/control-truetype-font-tracking-in-fontforge

Comment: Sounds like a DTP thing rather than a font thing to me.